# Global variables in If statements - PHP

Tags: php, global-variables

I was looking for examples of using global variables in IF statements, found few but I still cannot make my code to work. I'm declaring variable globally and tried to assign values inside if statement and later to check if the variable contains certain value.  When I echo the variable, it is not updated with the value I'm assigning within if statement. My code:

```
<?php
    $cart = 0;

    if ((isset($_POST["b1"]) && $_POST["b1"] === "Add to cart")) { 
        global $cart; 
        $cart = 1;
        $query_HOD = "INSERT INTO orderLine 
                      (LINE_ID, PRODUCT_ID, QUANTITY, AMOUNT)
                      VALUES 
                      ('LINE1', '00001', 1, 6.99)";

        if ((isset($_POST["add"]) && $_POST["add"] === "Go to cart")) {
            echo $cart;
            if($cart === 1) {
                echo $cart;
                header("location:cart.php");
            }
            else {
                echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Your cart is empty');</script>";
            }
        }
?>
```

isset methods are working fine, I have checked those, it seems to me that the variable is updated but only locally and does not affect the global variable.

Comment: Shouldn't you define global outside the if code? Plus I have the feeling you should work with cookies instead.

Comment: I have tried that as well, with the same results, could you elaborate bit more why should I work with cookies instead please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps you're expecting a *global* variable to mean a variable that persists between requests; that's not what they are. A global is just a variable that is accessible anywhere in your code *for that request*. As @user1231958 stated, you'll want a cookie or some other way to persist state.

Comment: All I want to achieve at this stage is to check if any of the options has been selected and then proceed to cart, it's supposed to be simple checking mechanism, could I achieve it using cookies?

Comment: If you want to store stuff within a "session" (sequence of requests for one user), I'd use a PHP session. That will cause a session ID cookie to be passed around, and then you can do something like `$_SESSION["cart"] = "1"` and `if ($_SESSION["cart"] == "1")`.

Comment: Jacob, maybe it's a good idea to add a short example on cookies for other users? And Joe, global variables are not persistent, once the request is over (i.e. the website is loaded) the variable is gone. That's why you want cookies, those are stored between sessions (and maybe you should also persist the operation in the database).